# TPopup Arrow Position

Tags: delphi, popup, firemonkey, stringgrid

I have a delphi project that creates a TPopup when I put my mouse over a field in a StringGrid (Field is edited in a Memo so I wanted to have a fast way to read it).

The problem is: when I place the mouse over it the little "arrow" pointing to my StringGrid is not aligned with my mouse, my mouse is pointing to a corner of the Popup.

Is there a property that changes it's position? Or a way to allign it with the mouse pointer?

I've Already used these placements (and many others):

```
Balao.Placement := FMX.Controls.TPlacement.MouseCenter;
Balao.Placement := FMX.Controls.TPlacement.Mouse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that the little "arrow" comes from TCalloutPanel. Changed it to a TPanel and it got a lot better. But as most of my users use transparent styles I'm gonna have to use a TRectangle otherwise the text is impossible to read